# if i have a listview of checkbox listTile,how can i select all and unselect all and delete all in the list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview of checkbox listTile and a single checkbox to select all, I need when the single checkbox value is true (it is selected) to select all items in the listview to be able to delete all selected items

Comment: please share the code. so we can better understand the problem